# Moving instances from Set to another in Scala

Tags: android, performance, scala, set

In a game I need to keeps tabs of which of my pooled sprites are in use. When "active" multiple sprites at once I want to transfer them from my `passivePool` to `activePool` both of which are immutable HashSets (ok, i'll be creating new sets each time to be exact). So my basic idea is to along the lines of:

```
activePool ++= passivePool.take(5)
passivePool = passivePool.drop(5)
```

but reading the scala documentation I'm guessing that the 5 that I take might be different that the 5 I then drop. Which is definitely not what I want. I could also say something like:

```
val moved = passivePool.take(5)
activePool ++= moved
passivePool --= moved
```

but as this is something I need to do pretty much every frame in realtime on a limited device (Android phone) I guess this would be much slower as I will have to search one by one each of the `moved` sprites from the `passivePool`.

Any clever solutions? Or am I missing something basic? Remember the efficiency is a primary concern here. And I can't use Lists instead of Sets because I also need random-access removal of sprites from activePools when the sprites are destroyed in the game.

Comment: 1. Why do you think the first version is more efficient than the second one. 2. I suggest using mutable maps for your problem; this is just a feeling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing like benchmarking for getting answers to these questions.  Let's take 100 sets of size 1000 and drop them 5 at a time until they're empty, and see how long it takes.

```
passivePool.take(5); passivePool.drop(5)                    // 2.5   s
passivePool.splitAt(5)                                      // 2.4   s
val a = passivePool.take(5); passivePool --= a              // 0.042 s
repeat(5){ val a = passivePool.head; passivePool -= a }     // 0.020 s
```

What is going on?

The reason things work this way is that immutable.HashSet is built as a hash trie with optimized (effectively `O(1)`) add and remove operations, but many of the other methods are not re-implemented; instead, they are inherited from collections that don't support add/remove and therefore can't get the efficient methods for free.  They therefore mostly rebuild the entire hash set from scratch.  Unless your hash set has only a handful of elements in it, this is bad idea.  (In contrast to the 50-100x slowdown with sets of size 1000, a set of size 100 has "only" a 6-10x slowdown....)

So, bottom line: until the library is improved, do it the "inefficient" way.  You'll be *vastly* faster.

Comment: Thank you, this was very interesting and surprising! And yes, I think especially with Scala's collections, I shouldn't try to use common sense but measure instead.

Answer (score 4):

I think there may be some mileage in using `splitAt` here, which will give you back both the five sprites to move and the trimmed pool in a single method invocation:

```
val (moved, newPassivePool) = passivePool.splitAt(5)
activePool ++= moved
passivePool = newPassivePool
```

Bonus points if you can assign directly back to `passivePool` on the first line, though I don't think it's possible in a short example where you're defining the new variable `moved` as well.

Comment: i knew there had to be something similar to partition but for just taking/dropping. Thanks!